# Create a bash script that creates 30 processes of sleep

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash script that creates 30 processes of `sleep 1000 &.` using a `while` loop and run it.

```
!/bin/bash

count = 0
while [$count -le 30]

do

count = `sleep 1000& $count +1`
echo $count
done
```

Comment: Put your script into https://shellcheck.net/ fix the obvious errors. Then you can come back here (to this question) with your fixed script and any outstanding issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (with my annotations):

```
!/bin/bash
# missing '#' on line above

count = 0
# assignments should not have spaces around '='
# also, start at 1 or use `-lt` below to get 30 instead of 31 processes

while [$count -le 30]
# '[' and ']' *should* have spaces inside

do

count = `sleep 1000& $count +1`
# I can see what you're getting at, but it's wrong

echo $count
done

# (possibly) missing 'wait'
```

With spaces around `=` in the assignment in your code, the shell will interpret the line as "run the utility `count` with arguments `=` and `0`". That's why you should not have spaces around `=` in assignments.

`[ "$count" -le 30 ]` is exactly the same as `test "$count" -le 30`. In fact, `[` is a command (`/bin/[`, but often built into the shell for speed) that takes the same arguments as the `test` utility, but that requires an extra last argument that should be `]`.  That's where the space requirements of `[` and `]` comes from.

There should be a call to `wait` at the end of the script. The `wait` utility will wait for all background tasks (your `sleep 1000` calls) to finish. Without the `wait` you will start 30 processes that will be left running in the background when the script ends.  This may be what you want though.

Corrected code:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0

while [ "$count" -lt 30 ]; do
    sleep 1000 &
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
    echo "$count"
done

wait
```

Alternatively,

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( count = 0; count < 30; ++count )); do
    sleep 1000 &
    echo "$count"
done

wait
```

Sometimes you'd see something like

```
for count in {0..29}; do
    sleep 1000 &
    echo "$count"
done

wait
```

... but I do not personally like that type of loop since the shell must expand `{0..29}` into the list `0 1 2 3 4 ... 29` before the loop starts.  I think it's inelegant, but that's a personal opinion.

I have used `echo "$count"` in my code above.  Usually when outputting variable data I'd use `printf` since that's generally safer:

```
printf '%d\n' "$count"
```

See e.g. [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

I have also quoted the expansion af `$count` throughout. One could argue that this is not needed since we know exactly what values the variable will have, but it's a good practice nonetheless.  See e.g. [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Proper indentation helps with reading, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version.

`~$ num=1; while ((num<=30)); do sleep 1000 & ((num++)); done`

`~$ pgrep sleep | wc -l
30`

A number can be auto-incremented with `((num++))`.